# Format of EJS and JST template files in rails-backbone gem

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I am using the rails-backbone gem ( https://github.com/codebrew/backbone-rails). For rendering HTML, it uses some kind of javascript templates, whose name I cannot tell even after a few hours of search.

For example, it generates such a file for the view template:

```
# company.jst.ejs
<td><%= name %></td>
<td><%= tid %></td>

<td><a href="#/<%= _id %>">Show</td>
<td><a href="#/<%= _id %>/edit">Edit</td>
<td><a href="#/<%= _id %>/destroy" class="destroy">Destroy</a></td>
```

My questions are: what is .jst format? And in Rails 3.1, what library processes it? Same question for the .ejs extension. And what's the name of this template engine? Underscore?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Rails processes EJS templates with [ejs gem](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-ejs/) which is a port of underscore.js's [_.template](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template) function to Ruby. Output of that is a javascript function which in turn will produce the html when run in the browser.

- .ejs – embedded javascript
- .jst – javascript template

Here's recent article which includes also description of [backbone-rails](https://github.com/codebrew/backbone-rails):

- [Where does my javascript code go? Backbone, JST and the Rails 3.1 asset pipeline](http://patshaughnessy.net/2011/6/28/where-does-my-javascript-code-go-backbone-jst-and-the-rails-3-1-asset-pipeline)