# How to use EJS templates with backbone.marionette?

Tags: templates, backbone.js, ejs, marionette

So far I have been using EJS templates in my Rails/Backbone.js application.
I really want to start using [backbone.marionette](http://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette). What can I do to make it work with EJS?

```
MyView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  template: "#some-template"
});
```

It says in the docs that I need to provide a jQuery selector to the `template` attribute but I don't think that my EJS templates have one.

**Update:**

This is how I would use templates to render my views normally:

```
TasksTree.Views.TaskItem = Backbone.View.extend({
...
  render: function() {
    ...
    this.$el.html(JST['tasks_tree/item'](options));
    return this;
  }

})
```

And I have templates folder with `item.jst.ejs` file that looks like that:

```
<li>
  <label><%= taskTitle %></label>
</li>
```

My templates folder is included in `application.js`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a section in the docs that shows several examples of replacing the rendering mechanism, as well:

http://derickbailey.github.com/backbone.marionette/#backbone-marionette-renderer/custom-template-selection-and-rendering

Seeing that JST provides the templates for you, and you don't need to cache them in any other way, though, you could skip past most of the functionality built in to Marionette's `Renderer` object and replace the `render` function entirely.

```
Backbone.Marionette.Renderer.render = function(template, data){
  return JST[template](data);
}
```

You would also replace the use of teh `template` attribute on views with the template path instead of a jquery selector:

```
Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  template: "tasks_tree/item"
});
```

Hope that helps. If not, let me know.

Comment: I updated my question with more details. I am a little bit confused since I am new to this. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557238/format-of-ejs-and-jst-template-files-in-rails-backbone-gem) has description of how EJS works if it helps.

Comment: This is great! Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I found this reference to be quite helpful: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/wiki/Using-jst-templates-with-marionette

You could replace the `render` function with something along these lines, which provides better error handling and flexibility.

```
Marionette.Renderer.render = function(template, data) {
    if(typeof template === 'function') {
        return template(data);
    }
    else {
        if(!JST[template]) throw "Template '" + template + "' not found!";
        return JST[template](data);
    }
};
```

You can then specify the template path (as previously mentioned):

```
Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "tasks_tree/item"
});
```

Or if your template is very simple, you can use a function to return just a string:

```
Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: function(data) {
        return "<div>" + data.attribute + "</div>";
    }
});
```